# Proper method to implement Jest tests in Jenkins build

Tags: reactjs, docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jestjs

We're using **Jest** to perform our React.js unit tests (on the frontend) of our Node.js app which runs in a docker container.

We have set up a Pipeline in Jenkins but I'm unsure of the best way (or *best practice*) to include the tests as part of the pipeline.

The steps we have are the following:

1. Check out the code from source control
2. NPM install and npm run build (front-end)
3. Docker build + publish
4. Deploy app
5. Bump version
6. Git push
7. Docker cleanup

I have 3 main queries:

A. I'm assuming it's best to include `npm run test` between **Step 1** and  **Step 2** and if all tests pass successfully to move further?

B. But how are the snapshots handled? For example, if there's some change which occurred that generates a difference in a snapshot this will not be "checked" back into the source control.

C. I read that people use Cobertura, jest-junit, etc to have unit tests and coverage within Jenkins - what is the best?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good questions!

A. You can run tests after `npm install`. And if all tests pass you move further. Another common thing to do is to run linting or code style check.

B. A bad snapshot will fail tests. Which is why it's important to update snapshots before committing. If your jenkins is hooked up to a code review system, you may disable merges that fail builds, to make sure bad snapshots don't get on your master branch.

C. I have seen people use `jest-junit`, but that's only because there was a requirement to have the coverage report combined with a `junit` coverage report. If you don't have any particular requirements around the structure of the report, then the default report `jest` produces should be fine, and you don't need anything extra.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer! I will do this implementation, so far Cobertura seems to be working nicely but guess the default jest report can work too.